# Selenium is sending wrong Special Keys

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I want to send key `ENTER` in my code, but Selenium is sending BACKSPACE instead.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:9999', desired_capabilities={"debugConnectToRunningApp": 'false', "app": r"C:/windows/system32/cmd.exe"})
cmd_prmpt = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ConsoleWindowClass')
time.sleep(2)
cmd_prmpt.find_element_by_class_name('ConsoleWindowClass').send_keys('netsh')
cmd_prmpt.find_element_by_class_name('ConsoleWindowClass').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

So, after this program is executed, I get "nets" instead(h is erased due to ENTER acting as BACKSPACE)

What do I do to make my code work correctly?

Comment: which webdriver are you using?

Comment: @0m3r I am using winium

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess:
Do you have any hidden characters in your string, which you don´t see in you editor? Because caret H is the ASCII code for Backspace.

[Wikipedia: ^H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace#%5EH)

Second idea:
Did you make sure the field can hold more than 4 characters?